# How to change Maven build path for repository when building project in command line

Tags: java, maven, build, repository, war

I am building a `.war` file for my Maven project after checking out the project from SVN using:

```
mvn clean package
```

However, it appears that Maven search for the libraries (maven dependencies) based on the current location of the project folder. (Underlined in yellow as below image). The project was placed in `D:\DCA`

[image]

I want `mvn` to search for the libraries from my `.m2` repository folder instead of `D:\DCA\..`. I believe there is a config file or settings file somewhere which allows me to change the location of the repository for project building.

**So my question is**: Where/how can I change the path as underlined in yellow in the above image?

Comment: There must be something configured in your pom file which uses maven-install-plugin directly which is simply wrong...furthermore do not use images better use text in your post...Post the full pom file...

Answer (score 1):

After you have downloaded the maven, follow given simple steps to change maven local repository location to some other path.

- Navigate to path {M2_HOME}\conf\ where M2_HOME is maven installation
  folder.
- Open file settings.xml in edit mode in some text editor.
- Find  the tag  Update the desired path in the value of this
  tag.
- Save the file.
       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  ```
   <!-- localRepository
     | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
     |
     | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository -->

    <localRepository>E:/devsetup/M2</localRepository>



  </settings>
  ```

==============================================

Start maven with -X option (debug) and examine the beginning of the output.

There should be something like this

[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.

[DEBUG] Reading global settings from c:....\apache-maven-3.0.3\conf\settings.xml

[DEBUG] Reading user settings from c:.....m2\settings.xml

[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:....\repository

Here you can see from where Maven is picking up the setting.

====================================================

If you want to specify your own settings.xml
then

```
mvn --settings customSetting.xml clean install
```

or

```
mvn -s customSetting.xml clean install
```

Comment: I know how to change the local repository location. But what I wanted to know is which config/settings file stores the location of the path for the repository when we are using `mvn` command to build a war file. When using `mvn` command to build, it does not read from my default .m2 repository.

Comment: The configuration in settings.xml is not related to the question cause there is a call to maven-install-plugin:install-file which is part of the pom file...

Comment: Please post pom.xml of yours.